# Shell scripting - need help parsing a file containing lists of IP addresses

Tags: bash

Given a file of the following format:

```
whitelist_a=["10.2.3.4", "10.6.7.8"]
whitelist_b=["192.2.3.4", "192.6.7.8"]
```

How can I parse it and use `eval` to create local variables for each key-value pair that I can reference later in my script? This is what I've tried so far:

```
WHITELISTS=./whitelists.txt

IFS="="
while read -r name value
do
  eval "$name=${value}"
done < $WHITELISTS
```

If I temporarily change the `eval` to `echo` then from the output I can see the lines being parsed as expected:

```
whitelist_a=["10.2.3.4", "10.6.7.8"]
whitelist_b=["192.2.3.4", "192.6.7.8"]
```

However, switching back to `eval` I get `10.6.7.8]: command not found`, which I'm presuming is because the double quotes haven't been escaped. What do I need to change to make this work?

Comment: You don't need to `eval` the string rather use the `declare` built-in to initialize the variables. Also you don't need to set `IFS` globally throughout your script, but make it local to the `read` command as `while IFS== read -r key value; do      declare "$key"="$value"; done < whitelists.txt`

Comment: @AlexHarvey: I'm waiting for OP's clarification, if the dupe is valid, from the looks the question seems to parse the config value and set variables in the shell. It's been answered int the other question

Comment: @AlexHarvey: The RHS value doesn't matter as long as it's parsed out as in my first comment. It sets those variables as OP wants

Comment: @AlexHarvey: If people think its not a dupe as you claim it to be, they can re-open the post with enough reopen posts

Comment: @AlexHarvey: I don't think its ugly in any way as you claim it to be. It sets the shell variable to the value on the RHS which is what OP wants. Feel free to add a better logic if you have

Comment: @AlexHarvey: It is not mentioned anywhere, OP wants the RHS to be parsed as a JSON. I can see only terms to be used as a shell variable. If OP feels otherwise I would gladly re-open, but as of now it remains a dupe

Comment: @AlexHarvey In the interests of brevity I probably over-simplified the question. My actual use-case is that I'm ultimately trying to pass the array of IP addresses as an argument to `terraform apply` i.e. `terraform apply -var "whitelist_a=[\"10.2.3.4\", \"10.6.7.8\"]"` etc.

Comment: Oh. Can you just edit the source file instead? `gsed -i 's/=\(.*\)/='\''\1'\''/' whitelists.txt ; source whitelists.txt`. That just turns the source file into valid Bash code. Or the other way suggested above.

Comment: Seems like you could also just pass the file as-is to `terraform apply -var-file=whitelists.txt`. https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/getting-started/variables.html